# How to hide and unhide CSS submenu in asp.net in master page that required user to log in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a MasterPage with a menu and submenu. I want to hide the submenu name Equipment List when the user open my website. After the user log in I want to show the Equipment List menu. Can anyone help me do it?

```css
  body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#menuwrapper ul {
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#submenu ul {
  margin: 0;
}

#menuwrapper ul li {
  background-color: #555555;
  border-bottom: solid 2px white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menuwrapper ul li:hover {
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
  position: relative;
}

#menuwrapper ul li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#submenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul {
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  display: block;
}

#menuwrapper ul li ul li {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
}

#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul li:hover {
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
}

#menuwrapper ul li ul li a {
  color: #555555;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
```

```html
<div id="menuwrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:25px; color:white"></i>
      <a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-wrench" style="font-size:25px; color:white"></i>
      <a href="#">Equipment List</a>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="font-size:25px; color:white"></i>
      <div id="submenu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:25px; color:#555555"></i>
            <a href="LoginNew.aspx">New Form</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:25px; color:#555555"></i>
            <a href="LoginUpdate.aspx">Update Form</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size:25px; color:#555555"></i>
            <a href="LoginDelete.aspx">Delete</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:25px; color:#555555"></i>
            <a href="tester.aspx">Tester</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:25px; color:#555555"></i>
            <a href="Asset.aspx">Asset</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:25px; color:#555555"></i>
            <a href="Iventory.aspx">Iventory</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- assuming you are using form authentication

Use [Embedded Code Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx)

```
 <li>
  <i class="fa fa-wrench" style="font-size:25px; color:white"></i>
  <a href="#">Equipment List</a>
    <% if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ) { %>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="font-size:25px; color:white"></i>
      <div id="submenu">
        // more HTML here
      </div>
    <% } %>
 </li>
```

Comment: hi sir, What is Embedded Code Block? For your information I just using the normal log in. That have username and password. The username and password I store in the database name details.@ShekharPankaj

Comment: @Moon https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx.. Embedded code blocks..
Google  `Form authentication in Asp.net`, Probably you must be using the same in your app.